# How can I cross-reference one Sphinx LateX document from another?

Tags: pdf, latex, python-sphinx, cross-reference

I have a Sphinx documentation project with a Developer's Manual and a Reference Manual in separate subdirectories, resulting in a single set of HTML docs with both manuals, but separate LaTeX PDF manuals for each.

The goal is to have text in the Reference Manual, for example, that says ...

> *Please see the **Models** section in the **Developer's Manual** for more details.*

... where **Models** and **Developer's Manual** are direct links to the appropriate section/page.

I use cross references in both manuals with explicit targets, like `` :ref:`model_section` ``  and `` :ref:`dev_manual` `` . They all work beautifully in the HTML version, including from one manual to the other. But in the LaTeX PDF output, links within each manual are fine, but links from one manual to the other are rendered as the name of the target (e.g. "model_section" and "dev_manual") in plain text.

How can I at least get the cross-references to render with the appropriate text (section/page title) in the PDF version, if not be a functioning link? I'd like to avoid having to put the text in the `ref` role explicitly.

Comment: Having a similar issue. Just for clarity, are you also using the `latex_documents` config option to make the individual .tex files? (https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-latex_documents)

Comment: From a purely latex point of view, there is a very similar question and set of solutions here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14364/cross-referencing-between-different-files 

Perhaps there's a way to leverage that from sphinx.

Comment: Yes, @partofthething, I am using the `latex_documents` config option. So far, I have still not found a solution to this issue.

Comment: I went ahead and made an issue describing this problem at: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/12063